# How to select an option automatically from a prompt message in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, rhel

when i run my script manually it prompts a message to select YES or NO . I am automating this part in shell scripting, how to automatically select YES

script.sh - if i run this it should take the option YES by default

Comment: `man yes` .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple, i just simply gave an echo

script.sh - main script

```
#!/bin/bash
some_process
echo YES | process
```